# Error of multi cluster writes when running a Spark Structured Streaming job with the Databricks merge API

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I noticed that some of my jobs have a weird behavior.
I have several streaming jobs that sometimes fail (for different reasons) and when I run them again, they succeed.

But I've got other streaming jobs (those jobs all use the Databricks' merge API inside a foreachBatch) and once they fail once, they can never run again because I always end up with the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find the API URL to send http requests. The current mode doesn't support transactional writes from different clusters. You can disable multi-cluster writes by setting 'spark.databricks.delta.multiClusterWrites.enabled' to 'false'. If this is disabled, writes to a single table must originate from a single cluster. Please check https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-intro.html#frequently-asked-questions-faq for more details.
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.DriverAPITokenProvider.$anonfun$getApiUrl$2(S3LogStore.scala:561)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.DriverAPITokenProvider.getApiUrl(S3LogStore.scala:558)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.DriverAPITokenProvider.getToken(S3LogStore.scala:520)
at com.databricks.s3commit.AutoRefreshAPITokenProvider.getCandidateToken(APITokenProvider.scala:252)
at com.databricks.s3commit.AutoRefreshAPITokenProvider.getToken(APITokenProvider.scala:222)
at com.databricks.s3commit.RestClientContext.apiToken(S3CommitRestClient.scala:17)
at com.databricks.s3commit.S3CommitRestClientImpl.commit(S3CommitRestClient.scala:78)
at com.databricks.s3commit.S3CommitClientImpl.$anonfun$commit$1(S3CommitClient.scala:249)
at com.databricks.s3commit.S3CommitClientImpl.runWithExponentialBackoffRetry(S3CommitClient.scala:417)
at com.databricks.s3commit.S3CommitClientImpl.commit(S3CommitClient.scala:250)
at com.databricks.s3commit.S3CommitClientImpl.commit(S3CommitClient.scala:229)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedS3AFileSystem.$anonfun$putIfAbsent$2(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:296)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.s3a.utils.S3AExeceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:21)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedS3AFileSystem.$anonfun$putIfAbsent$1(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:296)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedS3AFileSystem.withAttributionContext(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:240)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedS3AFileSystem.withAttributionTags(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:240)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedS3AFileSystem.recordOperation(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:240)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.EnhancedS3AFileSystem.putIfAbsent(EnhancedFileSystem.scala:295)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.MultiClusterLogStore.$anonfun$write$4(S3LogStore.scala:498)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.s3commit.S3CommitClient$.withClient(S3CommitClient.scala:457)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.RestClientContextHelper$.$anonfun$runWithRestClientContext$1(S3LogStore.scala:625)
at com.databricks.s3commit.RestClientContext$.withRestClientContext(S3CommitRestClient.scala:33)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.RestClientContextHelper$.runWithRestClientContext(S3LogStore.scala:624)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.MultiClusterLogStore.write(S3LogStore.scala:489)
at com.databricks.tahoe.store.DelegatingLogStore.write(DelegatingLogStore.scala:117)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.$anonfun$doCommit$1(OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.scala:309)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaLog.lockInterruptibly(DeltaLog.scala:170)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.doCommit(OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.scala:292)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.doCommit$(OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.scala:288)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.doCommit(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImpl.$anonfun$doCommitRetryIteratively$2(OptimisticTransaction.scala:622)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:115)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:56)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:129)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:70)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:57)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:85)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:402)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:381)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:113)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:97)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordDeltaOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImpl.$anonfun$doCommitRetryIteratively$1(OptimisticTransaction.scala:618)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaLog.lockInterruptibly(DeltaLog.scala:170)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImpl.doCommitRetryIteratively(OptimisticTransaction.scala:613)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImpl.doCommitRetryIteratively$(OptimisticTransaction.scala:610)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.doCommitRetryIteratively(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.$anonfun$commit$1(OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.scala:241)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:115)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:56)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:129)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:70)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:57)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:85)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:402)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:381)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:113)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:97)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordDeltaOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.commit(OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.scala:170)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.commit$(OptimisticTransactionImplEdge.scala:166)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.commit(OptimisticTransaction.scala:91)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.$anonfun$run$2(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:187)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:150)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:208)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.$anonfun$run$1(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:150)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.executeThunk$1(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:919)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.$anonfun$recordMergeOperation$7(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:934)
at com.databricks.spark.util.NoopProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:52)
at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.DeltaProgressReporterEdge.withStatusCode(DeltaProgressReporterEdge.scala:30)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.DeltaProgressReporterEdge.withStatusCode$(DeltaProgressReporterEdge.scala:25)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.withStatusCode(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:80)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.$anonfun$recordMergeOperation$6(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:934)
at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:115)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:56)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:129)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:70)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:57)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:85)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:402)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:381)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.recordOperation(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:80)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:113)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:97)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.recordDeltaOperation(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:80)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.recordMergeOperation(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:931)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.MergeIntoCommandEdge.run(MergeIntoCommandEdge.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3789)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3787)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:92)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.$anonfun$execute$2(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:242)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:60)
at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:147)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:469)
at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogger.scala:468)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.withAttributionTags(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:126)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordAPILang(DeltaLogging.scala:126)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordAPILang$(DeltaLogging.scala:123)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.recordAPILang(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:126)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.$anonfun$execute$1(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:242)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError(AnalysisHelper.scala:88)
at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError$(AnalysisHelper.scala:76)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.improveUnsupportedOpError(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:126)
at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.execute(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:239)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I know the code is ok because each time I get this error, I "just have" to trash my table and the associated checkpoint, recreate the table, run the job again and everything is fine.

Unfortunately it's impacting our production because as time passes my tables have more and more data and I can't accept deleting and re-generating the whole table each time the jobs fail.

Here's what my code look like for all those jobs :

```
def handle_batch(self, df, batch_id):
    updates = # compute updates with df

    table = DeltaTable \
        .forName(self.spark, 'the_table_i_want_to_update')

    table \
        .alias('old') \
        .merge(updates.alias('new'), 'old.key = new.key') \
        .whenMatchedUpdate(
        set={'field': 'new.field'}) \
        .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
        .execute()

def run(self):
    delta = self.spark \
        .readStream \
        .option("ignoreDeletes", "true") \
        .option("ignoreChanges", "true") \
        .format("delta") \
        .table('the_table_to_read')

    query = delta \
        .writeStream \
        .foreachBatch(self.handle_batch) \
        .option("checkpointLocation", 'the_checkpoint_path') \
        .trigger(once=True) \
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

Any idea why this happens ? It's almost like when it fails during the merge, some metadata stays somewhere and when I run the job again I get the error because the runtime thinks there is two simultaneous writes.

Comment: I think the error tells u enuff...

Comment: I already tried what the message is saying, it does nothing the job still fails.